# В чем разница между двумя кусками кода CSS

Tags: css

в чем разница между двумя кусками кода?

**1 КУСОК**

```
#parent div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**2 КУСОК**

```
#parent > div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: [Селектор дочерних элементов](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) и [Селектор потомков](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

#parent > div - означает что стили будут применены ко всем дивам, которые являются прямыми потомками парент.

#parent div - означает что стили будут применены ко всем дивам, которые находятся внутри парент.

Comment: _#parent > div - означает что стили будут применены только к первому дииу, который находится в парент._ - это неверное утверждение

Comment: Да, немного не так написал, селектор > означает что выбирает только прямых потомков.

Comment: отредактируй свой ответ. Отредактировать можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под ответом

Comment: И чем этот ответ отличается от моего?

Answer (score 1):

Запись `#parent div` означает тег `div` внутри элемента с идентификатором `parent`.

А `#parent > div` означает почти то же самое, но только не просто внутри, а на первом уровне вложенности, т.е. так работать будет:

```css
#parent > div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div>Some text.</div>  <!-- тег на первом уровне вложенности -->
</div>
```

а так нет

```css
#parent > div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <a>
    <div>Some text.</div>  <!-- тег на втором уровне вложенности -->
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: А если добавишь сниппет, то увидишь, что ни один из твоих примеров не сработает.